# Getting Wikidata IDs for known Geonames IDs

Tags: geonames, wikidata

We have geocoded an EXCEL table of placenames with the Geonames API and also extracted the Geonames IDs. We are now looking for a way to include the Wikidata IDs where possible.

What is the best way to extract the IDs from Wikidata based on the known Geonames IDs?

Here is how to find the Wikidata ID for a single place via the SPARQL interface:

```
SELECT * 
{  
?place wdt:P1566 "2968815"
}
```

Is there a way to batch-extract Wikidata IDs, e.g. using Python packages like [Wikimapper](https://pypi.org/project/wikimapper/)?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works